# When i use a media tag it crashes my website

Tags: css, media-queries

This code seems to be correct but when i add it to my CSS it crashes the site. What did i do wrong?

CODE USED:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sesusercoverphoto_cover_change_cover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px !Important;
    z-index: 2;
  }
```

Comment: First, are you missing a closing bracket there?  If not, try creating a page with just that rule and elements that match the rule.  If it works, copy your site and then divide and conquer - remove elements until it doesn't crash.  That will give you a good idea as to what's causing the crash in conjunction with this rule.

Comment: What do you mean by *"crash"*? It looks weird? It throws a legitimate error? The browser crashes?

Comment: Please provide enough code to reliably replicate the problem, best as a [mcve],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a second closing bracket.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sesusercoverphoto_cover_change_cover {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 20px !Important;
    z-index: 2;
  }
}
```